# Equal Distribution of Hash Partition in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to have a equal distribution on APPID and want to use HASH PARTITION..

```
create table AVAILABLE_WEB_DETAILS4
(
  "5mintime" TIMESTAMP,
  username VARCHAR2(64) DEFAULT cast('UNKNOWN' as VARCHAR2(7)),
  host number,
  src_zone VARCHAR2(32),
  domain VARCHAR2(512),
  dst_zone VARCHAR2(32),
  content VARCHAR2(64),
  category VARCHAR2(64),
  url VARCHAR2(1024),
  hits number DEFAULT 1, 
  bytes number, 
  appid VARCHAR2(32),  
  application VARCHAR2(64),
  categorytype VARCHAR2(64) DEFAULT cast('UNKNOWN' as VARCHAR2(7)),
  usergroup VARCHAR2(384) DEFAULT cast('UNKNOWN' as VARCHAR2(7))
)
partition by hash(APPID)
partitions 4
store in (IVIEWDB);
```

I have inserted 6 rows but all are going in one partition only..i want to distribute data equally among all partitions..any idea for it..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6 rows isn't really a high enough `n` -- the probability that the hash function, whatever Oracle uses, returns the same hash modulo 4 for 6 rows is quite high.

I'd try with, say, 1000 or 10000 rows to see if the partitioning actually works reasonably well (ie. let's say 225-275 (or 2250-2750) rows per partition).

Comment: If Hash values of APPID column is mostly same..then how will it equally distribute..??.(i.e.my APPID goes like 1,10,1000,then for all this hash value it will go in same partition).

Comment: Are they _actually_ mostly the same for your expected values? If so, then alright -- you have a corner case in which you'll need to use a different hashing function that behaves properly for your data.